# How to get module changes in build in angular 6?

Tags: build, angular6, node-modules

In angular6, I have do some customize in `node-module` and I run in local it works fine in local.

When I make build using `ng build --prod` and make it live, then it doesn't take changes of module.

So any once can help or suggest me in build to get changes of `node-module` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to make build using this command.

```
ng build --aot
```